Picking multiple random JLabels from a JLabel array
I have an array of 256 JLabels. I'm trying to pick 40 random labels, and assign them a new name.
I've tried using a random int method, but I'm not able to convert that to a JLabel.
I'm newer to java. Any help is appreciated

You need to put some of your code here in your question. Include your declaration of your array of JLabels.  As it is, your question is unanswerable.  If you have an array already JLabel[] and randomly pick #17 what you should get out of the array is already a JLabel and wouldn't need to be converted... so show the code of what you're doing.

Pick the text or image from an array of text or images.  The 40 JLabels should be defined once and only once in your GUI and reused.

Take the following steps:

Put the references to the JLabel instances in a List, e.g. using List<JLabel> list = Arrays.asList(array);.
Then shuffle the list using Collections.shuffle(list). Use Collections.shuffle(list, new SecureRandom()) if you want to really shuffle it well.
Finally you can simply take the first int n = 40 references using list.subList(0, Math.min(n, list.size())). The Math.min is just there in case the number of labels changes.

And that's it.
